# "Раз в год" и "раз в году"

Tags: лексика

"Раз в год" и "раз в году" - в чем разница?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Раз в году - акцент на единичности события, на количестве раз в конкретном году: *День рожденья только раз в году* (а не 2, 3).

Раз в год = ежегодно, акцент на  обязательной периодичности: *Раз в год я бываю на родине.*

Если добавляется числительное 1, значения сближаются: *Один раз в год сады цветут* = только один раз.

Answer (score 0):

Две формы одного фразеологизма, отличающиеся только падежом слова *год*, — в.п. и п.п.